# How to move iMac without powering it down?

Tags: power-supply, power, imac

Sometimes, I need to move my iMac to another room without shutting it down. To do that, I need to unplug it from the electrical outlet and then I need to plug it to the outlet in the next room.

I've thought about doing it with UPS, however then I read about the UPS, I changed my mind about it as an option.

So what should I do?

PS: While I'm in the main room, I don't want to draw power for my iMac using the other room's outlet (or from any other room except the main one). That was one of my ideas. — But I can do it when I need to move my computer, but the question is how?

Comment: I'm sorry, what was it you read about UPS that changed your mind? Did you mean to include a link?

Comment: Also, moving computers while powered on is a problem, especially computers not designed to be portable. They are engineered in a way that keeps the components safe and secure under the conditions the computer is designed to be used within. So laptops have a rigidity and design that allows them to function safely while moving, while desktops, such as your iMac, are designed to be safe when they are securely stationed on a desk. I understand you may consider it necessary to not power the computer off, but realistically you are inviting a much higher chance of hardware fault with this choice.

Comment: If you need a computer in the second room, get a cheap laptop or tablet.  Don't risk dropping and breaking your desktop.

Comment: @Spiff It is this link: https://superuser.com/questions/317976/is-it-okay-to-use-a-ups-without-a-ground

Comment: @music2myear Yes, I agree on some grounds but I don't think that any hardware failure will occur while moving my iMac, especially because it doesn't have any moving parts.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Yes, I've a laptop as well but its screen is smaller, and I don't want to connect a monitor to it. I want only to use my iMac because it's inconvenient to work with several computers in a day (MacBook Pro 15" -> iMac -> MacBook Pro 15").

Comment: "I don't think that any hardware failure will occur while moving my iMac, especially because it doesn't have any moving parts."  @InancGumus , it is your risk and expense.  I will put in an answer with some ideas in an answer below.  Hopefully one of those will work for you.

Comment: That link is about grounding. If the outlet in one or both of the rooms is not grounded, it's considered a safety issue to plug your iMac into that outlet, but a UPS doesn't make the safety concern any worse I wouldn't think. Just use a UPS.

Answer (score 2):

Using a cable reel might work, so your computer may stay plugged in all the time (but you can't close doors).

A portable computer might be a better solution in the long run. They even have a built-in UPS :)

Comment: Thanks but the problem with a portable computer is, their screens are small (I prefer to work with MacBook Pro which is 15").

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas, all of which have some expense:

1. Remote Desktop.  Set up VNC or another remoting solution. The guest may be another iMac (similar monitor but doesn't need to be as powerful), or a far cheaper PC with the monitor size you want. The OS doesn't need to be the same, and while it's in full screen you won't see the difference. Use whatever keyboard/mouse you want.
2. Long-range Second Monitor Mirroring, and wireless keyboard/mouse. Lay a long video cable (probably needs a long-range setup or drilling through the wall). Set up the iMac for mirroring.  When you walk to the second room, turn on the projector or monitor in the second room, and you see your desktop mirrored.  Long-range wireless keyboard/mouse required.
3. ANY OPTION WHICH INVOLVES MOVING THE IMAC IS EXPENSIVE AND DANGEROUS.  But if an executive came to me and wanted me to make such a setup, the minimum would be : Heavy Rolling Table, with a heavily-protected and reeled power cord screwed into the bottom of the tabletop. Drill a hole through the table to pass the iMac power cable through. Multi-outlet Uninterruptible Power Supply screwed into the bottom or leg of the table with many screws, with audible alarm and a large battery. The iMac itself must be securely attached to the table - perhaps gimmick up something to hold the base down. Make sure that there is slack in every power cord, and that no power cord bears tension except the reel which is made for it.

Assumptions on my part: I'm assuming you aren't using Ethernet for network, or cables for keyboard/mouse. I'm assuming your floor is flat and your doors and archways are large. I'm assuming you have the strength to move a table without trouble.

All options which involve moving the iMac will give you grief someday.  At some point, you will trip, the power will come undone, the iMac will topple, and you will be very sad.  It might still be functional, or it might require you to recreate the entire setup on an entire new, very expensive iMac.